# Possible Growth Function for a hypothesis set

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to resolve a homework problem. 
How do I determine the possible growth function $mH(N)$ for some hypothesis set?
My choices are  $1,2^N,2^\sqrt{N},N^2-N+2$ and none.

My research :
I understand that the growth function counts the most dichotomies on any $N$ points and the growth function satisfies $mH(N) <= 2^N$.

Also, $mH(3) = 2^3 = 8, mH(4) = 14 < 2^4,$ Where $H$ is the perceptron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of the VC dimension and the Sauer–Shelah lemma we know that the growth function can have only two types of behavior : polynomial (finite VC dim) or exponential (infinite VC dim) growth with respect to N.